# Rollapply for time series

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to calculate the rolling 20 period historical volatility. I take the daily returns:

```
ret <- ROC(data1)
```

And then I use rollapply to get the 20 day HV for each column:

```
vol <- rollapply(ret, 20, sd, by.column=T, fill=NA)
```

The problem is that observations in vol starts appearing after ten days which is wrong as I specified 20.

For demonstration here is sample of the data:

```
0.000000000, 0.005277045, 0.023622047, 0.002564103,-0.002557545, -0.020512821,
0.007853403,-0.012987013,  0.007894737,  0.015665796,  0.000000000, -0.002570694,
0.002577320, -0.015424165, 0.002610966,  0.010416667,  0.002577320,  0.015424165, 
0.000000000, -0.002531646, -0.002538071, 0.030534351,  0.014814815, -0.007299270,
-0.009803922, -0.012376238,  0.002506266, -0.015000000,-0.002538071,  0.002544529
```

Assume the data above is stored in x, then:

```
rollapply(x, 20, sd, fill=NA)
```

will yield a first observation at 10th row instead of 20. Also the sd is wrong too.

I should be missing something here...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `align='right'` instead of using the default which is `align='center'`, or instead of using `rollapply`, use the `rollapplyr` wrapper which has `align='right'` as the default.

From `?rollapply`:

> align 
>   specifyies whether the index of the result should be left- or right-aligned or centered (default) compared to the rolling window of observations. This argument is only used if width represents widths.

Although, for this, personally, I'd use `runSD` from the [**TTR**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=TTR) package because it uses compiled code and will be faster.

Either of these should do what you expect, but the second one will be faster.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(x, 20, sd, fill=NA, align='right')

library(TTR)
runSD(x, 20)
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend `runner` function in [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/apply_any_r_function.html) package to apply any R function on rolling windows. Below `runner` output identical to `zoo`.

```
library(runner)

runner(
  x, 
  function(x) sd(x),
  k = 20, 
  na_pad = TRUE
)
```

---

`runner` can reproduce `zoo` output and also have options like handling unequally spaced data and other (for more go to [documentation and vignettes](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/index.html) for more).

```r
library(runner)
library(zoo)

x <- c(0.000000000, 0.005277045, 0.023622047, 0.002564103,-0.002557545, -0.020512821,
       0.007853403,-0.012987013,  0.007894737,  0.015665796,  0.000000000, -0.002570694,
       0.002577320, -0.015424165, 0.002610966,  0.010416667,  0.002577320,  0.015424165, 
       0.000000000, -0.002531646, -0.002538071, 0.030534351,  0.014814815, -0.007299270,
       -0.009803922, -0.012376238,  0.002506266, -0.015000000,-0.002538071,  0.002544529)

identical(
  runner(x, sd, k = 20, na_pad = TRUE),
  rollapply(x, 20, sd, fill = NA, align = "right")
)

# centered alignment
identical(
  runner(x, sd, k = 20, lag = -10, na_pad = TRUE),
  rollapply(x, 20, sd, fill = NA, align = "center")
)
```